# eclipse error - javascript translation for intentionally not implemented

Tags: eclipse

Whenever i am trying to write javascript in the jsp file using Eclipse IDE, getting one popup with error as 
    An internal error occurred during: "JavaScript translation for :
/Wireless/Login.jsp".

where Login.jsp is the jsp i am working on.

How to avoid this error while typing javascript.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.
Go to your workspace folder and find Workspace/.metadata/.mylyn folder.
Delete .mylyn folder and restart your eclipse.
you will not get the javascript error popup

Comment: How did you find this out?  If you got it from a Web resource, what is the URL?

Comment: I posted this question and kept trying from my side also. I did not find it on web, just got solution while following up the error message and liked to share the solution so that another person should not waste time.

Comment: Thank it seems to have fixed the problem!